# Sinon: force callback call

Tags: node.js, sinon

I'm testing a function with this code:

```
return new Promise((ok, fail) => {
  this.repository.findById(id, (error, result) => {
    if (error)
      return fail(error);
    ok(result);
  });
});
```

I want to test the path of the fail, i.e., when the `findById` method calls the callback with an error. I'm using sinon to generate a stub for my `repository` and its `findById` method, but I don't know how to force the stub to call the callback with the desired parameters

Anybody did something like that before?

Thanks

Comment: which sinon version are you using?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With Sinon 2, you can use the `callsFake` method of a stub:

```
sinon.stub(repository, 'findById').callsFake((id, callback) =>
    callback(new Error('oops'))
);
```

See Sinon 2 documentation: http://sinonjs.org/releases/v2.1.0/stubs/

Comment:  glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

A more generic answer here:
Every time I have to stub a callback, I do it like this

```
const stubFindId = sinon.stub(repository, 'findById');    
stubGetitem.callsFake((value: string, callback: any) => {
      return callback(true, false);
    });
```